# Simple Scan Not Detecting HP 1050-j410 All-In-One on network

Tags: networking, hp, scanner

I can print from my client laptop to my server desktop ok, but both Simple Scan & xsane will not detect the scanner. I am using an HP Deskjet 1050-j410 all in-one connected to the server by usb.Both client & server have lubuntu 16.04. There seems to be different ways in which to install & use an all-in one scanner, which one is the easiest & where can I find instructions please. I have tried sane & hplip without success.

Comment: HPLIP is the thing to try if nothing else works. If it doesn't work, this is going to be difficult. What exactly do you mean by "without success"? What are the error messages and behaviour of HPLIP?

Comment: I have been using https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne. HPLIP comes up with error HPLIP cannot detect printers in your network.
This may be due to existing firewall settings blocking the required ports. When you are in a trusted network environment, you may open the ports for network services like mdns and slp in the firewall. For detailed steps follow the link. http://hplipopensource.com/node/375                                         Even with both firewalls tuned off.

Comment: Using (ubuntu SaneDaemonTutorial) sudo systemctl enable saned.socket = Failed to execute operation: Invalid argument.  sudo systemctl start saned.socket = no response. systemctl status saned.socket =  ● saned.socket - saned incoming socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/saned.socket; bad; vendor preset: enabled
   Active: active (listening) since Thu 2016-10-20 12:30:11 BST; 6min ago
   Listen: [::]:6566 (Stream)
 Accepted: 0; Connected: 0
Oct 20 12:30:11 martyn-M830LU systemd[1]: Listening on saned incoming socket.
Oct 20 12:35:51 martyn-M830LU systemd[1]: Listening on - - - - -

Comment: I overlooked that the printer is directly connected to the server, so HPLIP is no help, as you have already recognized. The way via SANE is the way to go, but unfortunately, it's tricky. Once, I had no success either with what's available on the web and wrote this http://superuser.com/questions/985254/installation-of-saned-with-systemd-no-inetd-or-xinetd-saned-refuses-connecti to document my steps. Maybe this helps.

Comment: I have uninstalled hplip from my client laptop, but I still have hplip installed on my server desktop for printer maintenance, is that ok.                   I am also in touch with sane-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org to see if they can help. I am trying to make sense of superuser.com/questions/985254/installation-of-saned-with-systemd-no-inetd-or-xinetd-saned-refuses-connecti

Comment: hplip could interfere; best to remove it, at least temporarily. What SANE version do you run on the server? What's the output of `scanimage -L` on the server?

Comment: I have now uninstalled hplip from both server & client. My sane version is  1.0.25. Do I need libsystemd-dev installed on both server & client?

Comment: No. Run `scanimage -L`, on server and client, what's the output?

Comment: scanimage -L output No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
martyn@martyn-M830LU:~$

Comment: Where should I install libsystemd-dev, server or client?

Comment: Nowhere. You don't need the dev files. systemd needs to be running on the server. That is all. Look to my linked answer for next steps and output if it runs.

Comment: Uninstalled hplip from server. Scanner no longer works on server. Simple Scan error, Additional Drivers needed, I click on install drivers, error failed to install drivers once installed you need to restart Simple Scan.      scanimage -L on both server & client = no sane devices found.                    Your linked answer says "In short, libsystemd-dev needs to be installed for the systemd glue to work, and the saned.service edited to match the man page suggestion for 1.0.25: 1.0.25 man page"????

Comment: Ah, I see were the confusion comes from. Since you have already the 1.0.25 version, all this is unnecessary. It was just to catch to changes already in there while the new version was not in the repos. You need to purge `sane` and reinstall `hplip` and set it up so that your printer is recognized. `hplip` is using `sane` under the hood, so they interfere. It's one or the other.

If everything is setup correctly, the `scanimage -L` from above should work on server and client and show the printer/scanner.

Comment: If `hplip` doesn't set up your scanner for network access (`scanimage -L` works on server, but not on client), use the following tutorial to set it up for network access: After the scanner shows up on server and client with `scanimage -L`, follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaneDaemonTutorial?action=show&redirect=sane.d+tutorial (the systemd instructions). DO NOT reinstall sane. `hplip` pulls `sane` in and configures it. You need to add or modify the settings, not replace them with a stock version.

Comment: Purged sane, reinstalled hplip to server. scanner recognized by scanimage L on server but not client. Following tutorial I get stuck at sudo systemctl enable saned.socket= Failed to execute operation: Invalid argument. sudo systemctl start saned.socket= No response. systemctl status saned.socket= ● saned.socket - saned incoming socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/saned.socket; bad; vendor preset: enabled
   Active: active (listening) since Wed 2016-10-26 15:14:23 BST; 10min ago
   Listen: [::]:6566 (Stream)
 Accepted: 0; Connected: 0

Comment: You are close, but the last step is difficult. What is the result from `systemctl reset-failed saned.socket`? If it doesn't start again, please try with `systemctl start saned`.

Comment: (SERVER) systemctl reset-failed saned.socket=No response.                                                                                                                            systemctl start saned= Failed to start saned.service: Unit saned.service is masked.

Comment: `sudo systemctl unmask saned.service`, then `systemctl start saned`. Why was this masked?

Comment: sudo systemctl unmask saned.service= No response

Comment: Found this, not sure if it helps?                                                                                           https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1577137

Comment: That sure helps. Try #19 from there. I assumed enabling was done via `hplip`, but let's make sure. Next, check #13. Maybe you need #18 as well if the above doesn't help. If this doesn't work, I'm out of options.

Comment: Tried some of that, but no good. Thank you very much for all your help. I also give up.